# Jupyter Play widget skipping steps

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

**Update:** I've simplified my original question quite a bit.

I want to create an animated plot but my implementation is skipping frames.

```py
x = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
y = np.cos(3*x)

def f(i):
    plt.plot(x[:i],y[:i]);
    plt.gca().axis([0,5,-1,1])
    plt.gca().set_title(f'{i}')

interactive(f, i=Play(value=0, min=0, max=50, step=1))
```

[image]

Instead of my desired step size (1), it plays at about 5 steps per frame.

The bahavior happens on both the notebook and jupyterlab, and on both the inline and notebook frontends (`%matplotlib notebook`)

Comment: Could you give an example of your code with some randomised data as the input?

Comment: Note that noone can reproduce this without a [mcve].

Comment: I've added a simple example and a gif @ac24

Answer (score 1):

I think this is something to do with the time taken to execute the plotting function. Try to alter the `interval` between plotting, looks like this is specified in milliseconds.

```python
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import *

x = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
y = np.cos(3*x)

def f(i):
    plt.plot(x[:i],y[:i]);
    plt.gca().axis([0,5,-1,1])
    plt.gca().set_title(f'{i}')

interactive(f, i=Play(value=0, min=0, max=50, step=1, interval=500))
```

[image]